Rotate Arrowhead in 3D plot
I am trying to adjust my arrowheads in a (semi-automatic generated) 3D plot. Here is the main part of the code (sorry for quite some coordinates).
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% Default preamble
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
% Custom preamble from global variable:
\pgfplotsset{scale=6.0}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{roundcaps/.style={line cap=round}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines={none}, axis equal, view={{135}{35}}, zmin={-0.05}, zmax={1.0}, xmin={0.0}, xmax={1.0}, ymin={0.0}, ymax={1.0}]
    \addplot3[opacity={1.0}, no markers, roundcaps, line width={20}, color={black}, -{Stealth[length=6cm,sharp]}]
        coordinates {
            (1.0,1.6653345369377348e-16,1.6653345369377348e-16) (0.9998741276738751,0.01586596383480809,1.691547054941705e-16) (0.9994965423831851,0.03172793349806781,1.7173337350205642e-16) (0.998867339183008,0.04758191582374245,1.742688085515504e-16) (0.9979866764718844,0.06342391965656466,1.7676037236043756e-16) (0.9968547759519424,0.07924995685678861,1.7920743769085324e-16) (0.9954719225730846,0.09505604330418281,1.8160938850718686e-16) (0.9938384644612541,0.11083819990101114,1.8396562013116542e-16) (0.9919548128307953,0.1265924535737494,1.8627553939407811e-16) (0.9898214418809327,0.1423148382732853,1.885385647861034e-16) (0.9874388886763943,0.15800139597335003,1.9075412660270088e-16) (0.984807753012208,0.17364817766693047,1.9292166708803153e-16) (0.9819286972627067,0.18925124436041033,1.9504064057536965e-16) (0.9788024462147787,0.20480666806519082,1.9711051362447152e-16) (0.975429786885407,0.22031053278654075,1.9913076515586617e-16) (0.9718115683235417,0.23575893550942734,2.011008865820344e-16) (0.9679487013963562,0.25114798718107934,2.0302038193544292e-16) (0.963842158559942,0.26647381369003503,2.0488876799340142e-16) (0.9594929736144974,0.28173255684142984,2.0670557439971153e-16) (0.9549022414440739,0.2969203753282749,2.0847034378307625e-16) (0.9500711177409454,0.31203344569848723,2.1018263187224092e-16) (0.9450008187146685,0.3270679633174217,2.1184200760783587e-16) (0.9396926207859083,0.3420201433256688,2.1344805325089372e-16) (0.9341478602651067,0.356886221591872,2.1500036448801249e-16) (0.9283679330160726,0.3716624556603277,2.164985505331396e-16) (0.9223542941045813,0.3863451256931288,2.1794223422595012e-16) (0.9161084574320695,0.4009305354066138,2.193310521267949e-16) (0.9096319953545183,0.4154150130018865,2.206646546081944e-16) (0.9029265382866212,0.42979491208917175,2.219427059428557e-16) (0.8959937742913359,0.4440666126057742,2.2316488438819e-16) (0.8888354486549234,0.45822652172741046,2.2433088226730963e-16) (0.881453363447582,0.4722710747726828,2.2544040604648394e-16) (0.8738493770697848,0.4861967361004689,2.2649317640903503e-16) (0.8660254037844386,0.5,2.27488928325654e-16) (0.857983413234977,0.5136773915734064,2.2842741112112095e-16) (0.8497254299495143,0.5272254676105025,2.2930838853741083e-16) (0.8412535328311811,0.5406408174555977,2.301316387931704e-16) (0.8325698546347713,0.5539200638661104,2.3089695463955034e-16) (0.8236765814298327,0.5670598638627707,2.3160414341237887e-16) (0.8145759520503357,0.5800569095711982,2.3225302708066444e-16) (0.8052702575310585,0.5929079290546404,2.328434422914136e-16) (0.7957618405308321,0.6056096871376666,2.333752404107545e-16) (0.7860530947427874,0.6181589862206052,2.338482875613544e-16) (0.7761464642917567,0.6305526670845225,2.3426246465612294e-16) (0.766044443118978,0.6427876096865394,2.3461766742819145e-16) (0.7557495743542583,0.654860733945285,2.349138064571615e-16) (0.7452644496757547,0.6667690005162916,2.3515080719161626e-16) (0.7345917086575332,0.6785094115571322,2.3532860996788836e-16) (0.7237340381050702,0.690079011482112,2.354471700250796e-16) (0.7126941713788628,0.7014748877063213,2.3550645751632967e-16) (0.7014748877063212,0.7126941713788629,2.3550645751632967e-16) (0.6900790114821119,0.7237340381050701,2.354471700250796e-16) (0.6785094115571321,0.7345917086575333,2.3532860996788836e-16) (0.6667690005162916,0.7452644496757548,2.351508071916163e-16) (0.6548607339452851,0.7557495743542583,2.349138064571615e-16) (0.6427876096865394,0.766044443118978,2.346176674281914e-16) (0.6305526670845225,0.7761464642917568,2.3426246465612294e-16) (0.6181589862206052,0.7860530947427875,2.338482875613544e-16) (0.6056096871376667,0.7957618405308321,2.333752404107545e-16) (0.5929079290546405,0.8052702575310584,2.328434422914136e-16) (0.5800569095711982,0.8145759520503357,2.3225302708066444e-16) (0.5670598638627709,0.8236765814298328,2.3160414341237887e-16) (0.5539200638661103,0.8325698546347714,2.3089695463955024e-16) (0.5406408174555976,0.8412535328311813,2.301316387931704e-16) (0.5272254676105023,0.8497254299495144,2.2930838853741083e-16) (0.5136773915734065,0.857983413234977,2.2842741112112095e-16) (0.5000000000000002,0.8660254037844387,2.2748892832565404e-16) (0.48619673610046865,0.8738493770697849,2.26493176409035e-16) (0.47227107477268276,0.8814533634475822,2.2544040604648394e-16) (0.4582265217274103,0.8888354486549236,2.2433088226730963e-16) (0.44406661260577407,0.895993774291336,2.2316488438819e-16) (0.4297949120891716,0.9029265382866211,2.2194270594285564e-16) (0.4154150130018865,0.9096319953545183,2.2066465460819438e-16) (0.4009305354066138,0.9161084574320696,2.1933105212679487e-16) (0.3863451256931286,0.9223542941045814,2.179422342259501e-16) (0.3716624556603275,0.9283679330160728,2.164985505331396e-16) (0.35688622159187194,0.9341478602651068,2.1500036448801246e-16) (0.34202014332566866,0.9396926207859084,2.1344805325089367e-16) (0.32706796331742183,0.9450008187146683,2.118420076078359e-16) (0.3120334456984871,0.9500711177409453,2.101826318722409e-16) (0.296920375328275,0.9549022414440739,2.0847034378307625e-16) (0.2817325568414296,0.9594929736144975,2.0670557439971153e-16) (0.266473813690035,0.9638421585599419,2.048887679934014e-16) (0.2511479871810793,0.9679487013963562,2.030203819354429e-16) (0.23575893550942734,0.9718115683235418,2.0110088658203443e-16) (0.2203105327865408,0.9754297868854069,1.9913076515586615e-16) (0.20480666806519068,0.9788024462147787,1.971105136244715e-16) (0.18925124436041027,0.9819286972627066,1.9504064057536962e-16) (0.17364817766693047,0.9848077530122079,1.9292166708803153e-16) (0.15800139597334986,0.9874388886763943,1.9075412660270083e-16) (0.14231483827328517,0.9898214418809326,1.8853856478610334e-16) (0.12659245357374935,0.9919548128307952,1.862755393940781e-16) (0.11083819990101115,0.9938384644612541,1.8396562013116542e-16) (0.09505604330418264,0.9954719225730846,1.8160938850718683e-16) (0.0792499568567885,0.9968547759519422,1.7920743769085319e-16) (0.06342391965656462,0.9979866764718841,1.7676037236043748e-16) (0.04758191582374246,0.998867339183008,1.742688085515504e-16) (0.03172793349806787,0.9994965423831851,1.7173337350205642e-16) (0.015865963834807987,0.999874127673875,1.6915470549417046e-16) (1.1674349118862548e-16,1.0,1.6653345369377348e-16)
        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The result looks as

Though there is Rotate arrowheads in tikz-3dplot which is similar, I am not able to apply this here, since this one arrow is just by chance in a plane (in this export).
I would like to

rotate the arrow head to align with the end of the line (slightly rotate it upwards)
if possible remove the end of the line to make the arrow head “sharp/pointy”.

I tried all possibilities explained in the arrows.meta docs (quick, flex, bend) none of them seems to have any effect.
So is there a way to rotate the arrow head while keeping the (seeming from an export, maybe read from a file) coordinates?

An arrow tip can only consider the last segment on a path. This is the one between your second to last and very last coordinate. And if you remove the arrow tip specification, you will see that the plot is actually longer. Remove a few coordinates and/or make the tip smaller. What's the point of the last 50 or so coordinates if you want them to be covered by the arrow tip?

That is a good remark that I did not see from the documentation. Sure it would be a bit of manual work, but I could in principle remove the ones that are “hidden under the arrow hat” anyways.

The problem (and hence solution) is indeed, that the direction of the arrow is computed by the last 2 samples. The plot above has 100.
So in my export I added a possibility to keep the last point but remove m points before, or in the example above, I removed the 25 points before the last point. That also solves the problem, that the arrow head was partly covered by a line.
Updated MWE
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% Default preamble
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
% Custom preamble from global variable:
\pgfplotsset{scale=6.0}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{roundcaps/.style={line cap=round}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines={none}, axis equal, view={{135}{35}}, zmin={-0.05}, zmax={1.0}, xmin={0.0}, xmax={1.0}, ymin={0.0}, ymax={1.0}]
    \addplot3[opacity={1.0}, no markers, roundcaps, line width={20}, color={black}, -{Stealth[length=6cm,sharp]}]
        coordinates {
            (1.0,1.6653345369377348e-16,1.6653345369377348e-16) (0.9998741276738751,0.01586596383480809,1.691547054941705e-16) (0.9994965423831851,0.03172793349806781,1.7173337350205642e-16) (0.998867339183008,0.04758191582374245,1.742688085515504e-16) (0.9979866764718844,0.06342391965656466,1.7676037236043756e-16) (0.9968547759519424,0.07924995685678861,1.7920743769085324e-16) (0.9954719225730846,0.09505604330418281,1.8160938850718686e-16) (0.9938384644612541,0.11083819990101114,1.8396562013116542e-16) (0.9919548128307953,0.1265924535737494,1.8627553939407811e-16) (0.9898214418809327,0.1423148382732853,1.885385647861034e-16) (0.9874388886763943,0.15800139597335003,1.9075412660270088e-16) (0.984807753012208,0.17364817766693047,1.9292166708803153e-16) (0.9819286972627067,0.18925124436041033,1.9504064057536965e-16) (0.9788024462147787,0.20480666806519082,1.9711051362447152e-16) (0.975429786885407,0.22031053278654075,1.9913076515586617e-16) (0.9718115683235417,0.23575893550942734,2.011008865820344e-16) (0.9679487013963562,0.25114798718107934,2.0302038193544292e-16) (0.963842158559942,0.26647381369003503,2.0488876799340142e-16) (0.9594929736144974,0.28173255684142984,2.0670557439971153e-16) (0.9549022414440739,0.2969203753282749,2.0847034378307625e-16) (0.9500711177409454,0.31203344569848723,2.1018263187224092e-16) (0.9450008187146685,0.3270679633174217,2.1184200760783587e-16) (0.9396926207859083,0.3420201433256688,2.1344805325089372e-16) (0.9341478602651067,0.356886221591872,2.1500036448801249e-16) (0.9283679330160726,0.3716624556603277,2.164985505331396e-16) (0.9223542941045813,0.3863451256931288,2.1794223422595012e-16) (0.9161084574320695,0.4009305354066138,2.193310521267949e-16) (0.9096319953545183,0.4154150130018865,2.206646546081944e-16) (0.9029265382866212,0.42979491208917175,2.219427059428557e-16) (0.8959937742913359,0.4440666126057742,2.2316488438819e-16) (0.8888354486549234,0.45822652172741046,2.2433088226730963e-16) (0.881453363447582,0.4722710747726828,2.2544040604648394e-16) (0.8738493770697848,0.4861967361004689,2.2649317640903503e-16) (0.8660254037844386,0.5,2.27488928325654e-16) (0.857983413234977,0.5136773915734064,2.2842741112112095e-16) (0.8497254299495143,0.5272254676105025,2.2930838853741083e-16) (0.8412535328311811,0.5406408174555977,2.301316387931704e-16) (0.8325698546347713,0.5539200638661104,2.3089695463955034e-16) (0.8236765814298327,0.5670598638627707,2.3160414341237887e-16) (0.8145759520503357,0.5800569095711982,2.3225302708066444e-16) (0.8052702575310585,0.5929079290546404,2.328434422914136e-16) (0.7957618405308321,0.6056096871376666,2.333752404107545e-16) (0.7860530947427874,0.6181589862206052,2.338482875613544e-16) (0.7761464642917567,0.6305526670845225,2.3426246465612294e-16) (0.766044443118978,0.6427876096865394,2.3461766742819145e-16) (0.7557495743542583,0.654860733945285,2.349138064571615e-16) (0.7452644496757547,0.6667690005162916,2.3515080719161626e-16) (0.7345917086575332,0.6785094115571322,2.3532860996788836e-16) (0.7237340381050702,0.690079011482112,2.354471700250796e-16) (0.7126941713788628,0.7014748877063213,2.3550645751632967e-16) (0.7014748877063212,0.7126941713788629,2.3550645751632967e-16) (0.6900790114821119,0.7237340381050701,2.354471700250796e-16) (0.6785094115571321,0.7345917086575333,2.3532860996788836e-16) (0.6667690005162916,0.7452644496757548,2.351508071916163e-16) (0.6548607339452851,0.7557495743542583,2.349138064571615e-16) (0.6427876096865394,0.766044443118978,2.346176674281914e-16) (0.6305526670845225,0.7761464642917568,2.3426246465612294e-16) (0.6181589862206052,0.7860530947427875,2.338482875613544e-16) (0.6056096871376667,0.7957618405308321,2.333752404107545e-16) (0.5929079290546405,0.8052702575310584,2.328434422914136e-16) (0.5800569095711982,0.8145759520503357,2.3225302708066444e-16) (0.5670598638627709,0.8236765814298328,2.3160414341237887e-16) (0.5539200638661103,0.8325698546347714,2.3089695463955024e-16) (0.5406408174555976,0.8412535328311813,2.301316387931704e-16) (0.5272254676105023,0.8497254299495144,2.2930838853741083e-16) (0.5136773915734065,0.857983413234977,2.2842741112112095e-16) (0.5000000000000002,0.8660254037844387,2.2748892832565404e-16) (0.48619673610046865,0.8738493770697849,2.26493176409035e-16) (0.47227107477268276,0.8814533634475822,2.2544040604648394e-16) (0.4582265217274103,0.8888354486549236,2.2433088226730963e-16) (0.44406661260577407,0.895993774291336,2.2316488438819e-16) (0.4297949120891716,0.9029265382866211,2.2194270594285564e-16) (0.4154150130018865,0.9096319953545183,2.2066465460819438e-16) (0.4009305354066138,0.9161084574320696,2.1933105212679487e-16) (1.1674349118862548e-16,1.0,1.6653345369377348e-16)
        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

with result

The 25 is a bit of a manual check, but roughly checking where the arrow end is does the trick. And none of the bend/flex/... keywords is necessary.
Thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel !
